# Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed any thoughts

Tags: sql, asp.net

I am using the following code to retrieve the column from the table

```
SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand();
SqlDataReader reader1 = null;            
cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
cmd1.Connection = conn;
cmd1.CommandText = "......";            
reader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

while (reader1.Read())
{
  Label32.Text = (reader["Unit"]).ToString();
}
```

The connection is open. My problem is that there is a lot of null values in the column, when the null value is retrieved from the table. It will give me the error "Invalid attempt to call MetaData when reader is closed." How could I solve the problem. Thanks.

The Exception was thrown on "Label32.Text = (reader["Unit"]).ToString();"

StackTrace:

```
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.CheckMetaDataIsReady()
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.GetOrdinal(String name)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_Item(String name)
at TSOD._1Test.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in h:\TSODNEW\TSOD\1Test.aspx.cs:line 75
at System.Web.Util.CalliEventHandlerDelegateProxy.Callback(Object sender, EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean                     includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
```

Comment: Is it really that line in the `while` loop that's throwing the exception?  Can you capture exactly which line throws the exception and include the stack trace?

Comment: `reader` should be `reader1["Unit"]`

Comment: @RickS, Thanks you so much to point out such a stupid mistake I made!

Comment: No problem.  Sometimes it takes a second set of eyes. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
while (reader1.Read())
{
  Label32.Text = (reader1["Unit"]).ToString();
}
```

Comment: oh, its been answered. Please close your question so no one expends  time trying to bring help you don't need any more. And thanks Rick S